# LPSolve - Setting constraints for the sum of multiple columns

Tags: r, linear-programming, lpsolve

I have a good grasp on using `LPSolve` for linear optimization problems, but one aspect has be stumped. I'd like to create a constraint for the sum of multiple columns. For example, I have a constraint that disallows any of four specific columns to be greater than 3. However, I require that **any one** of the four columns be equal to 3.

**WORKING EXAMPLE**

In this example I'm making meals to optimize "Value" while remaining under 5 individual items and $40 in cost. I also have four different food groups - meat, veggie, fruit, starch - and I require that the meal has no more than four items of any one group, but **any one group must have 3 items (this is where I'm getting stumped)**.

Below is the code that gets me the desired result except for the last constraint:

```
## Choose 5 food items remaining under $40 and maximizing Value ##
## There can be no more than 3 items from the same group chosen, but **there must be 3 items from at least one group**(??) ##

library(dplyr)
library(lpSolve)

# Constraints
totalItems <- 5
totalCost <- 40
maxAllGroups <- 3

# Setup problem
food <- c('Chicken', 'Beef', 'Lamb', 'Fish', 'Pork', 'Carrot', 'Lettuce', 'Asparagus', 'Beats', 'Broccoli', 'Orange', 'Apple', 'Pear', 'Banana', 'Watermelon', 'Potato', 'Corn', 'Beans', 'Bread', 'Pasta')
group <- c('Meat', 'Meat', 'Meat', 'Meat', 'Meat', 'Veggie', 'Veggie', 'Veggie', 'Veggie', 'Veggie', 'Fruit', 'Fruit', 'Fruit', 'Fruit', 'Fruit', 'Starch', 'Starch', 'Starch', 'Starch', 'Starch')
cost <- round(runif(length(food), 1, 20), 0)
value <- round(runif(length(food), 20, 60), 0)
df <- data.frame(food, group, cost, value, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>% 
  mutate(Total = 1)

# Value to be maximized
Value <- df$value

# Create constraint vectors
ConVec_Cost <- df$cost
ConVec_Items <- df$Total
# Make `Group` dummy variables
  groups <- unique(df$group)
  ConVec_Groups <- data.frame(row.names = 1:nrow(df))
  for(i in 1:length(groups)){
    currGroup <- groups[i]

    vec <- df %>% 
      mutate(isGroup = (group == currGroup)*1) %>% 
      select(isGroup)
    colnames(vec) <- currGroup

    ConVec_Groups <- cbind(ConVec_Groups, vec)
  }

# ConVec_AnyGroupEqual3 <- ???

ConVec_All <- t(cbind(ConVec_Cost, ConVec_Items, ConVec_Groups))

# Create constraint directions
ConDir_Cost <- "<="
ConDir_Items <- "=="
ConDir_Groups <- rep("<=", ncol(ConVec_Groups))
# ConDir_AnyGroupEqual3 <- "=="
ConDir_All <- c(ConDir_Cost, ConDir_Items, ConDir_Groups)

# Create constraint values
ConVal_Cost <- totalCost
ConVal_Items <- totalItems
ConVal_Groups <- rep(maxAllGroups, ncol(ConVec_Groups))
# ConVal_AnyGroupEqual3 <- 1 #1 group should have 3
ConVal_All <- c(ConVal_Cost, ConVal_Items, ConVal_Groups)

# Solve
sol <- lpSolve::lp("max",
                   objective.in = Value,
                   const.mat    = ConVec_All,
                   const.dir    = ConDir_All,
                   const.rhs    = ConVal_All,
                   all.bin      = TRUE
)

# Solution
df[sol$solution == 1,]
```

If I needed a specific Food-Group to have 3 then it would be easy, but the fact that I need any of the groups to be 3 is what makes it difficult. Is there a way to do this without resorting to `LPSolveAPI` (which I admittedly know little about)?

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out by dissecting someone's answer from a similar question a while back. Basically you have to add in 5 "dummy rows" (one for each food-group) with a value of -3 in the diagonal. Then, you have to add another column with all values being 0 except for the last 5 rows being 1 (the rows you just added to the matrix). You force the new column to be at least 1, which means one of those last 5 rows **must** be chosen.

Since one of those rows will be chosen, and that row adds a -3 to whatever food group it's on, *and* you have constraints that force each food group to be at least 0, then the -3 row that's chosen will force that food-group column to pick 3 so that the sum is >= 0.

**NEW CODE**

```
## Choose 5 food items remaining under $40 and maximizing Value ##
## There can be no more than 3 items from the same group chosen, but **there must be 3 items from at least one group**(??) ##

library(dplyr)
library(lpSolve)

# Constraints
totalItems <- 5
totalCost <- 40
minAllGroups <- 0
atLeastNFrom1 <- 3

# Setup problem
food <- c('Chicken', 'Beef', 'Lamb', 'Fish', 'Pork', 'Carrot', 'Lettuce', 'Asparagus', 'Beats', 'Broccoli', 'Orange', 'Apple', 'Pear', 'Banana', 'Watermelon', 'Potato', 'Corn', 'Beans', 'Bread', 'Pasta')
group <- c('Meat', 'Meat', 'Meat', 'Meat', 'Meat', 'Veggie', 'Veggie', 'Veggie', 'Veggie', 'Veggie', 'Fruit', 'Fruit', 'Fruit', 'Fruit', 'Fruit', 'Starch', 'Starch', 'Starch', 'Starch', 'Starch')
cost <- round(runif(length(food), 1, 20), 0)
value <- round(runif(length(food), 20, 60), 0)
df <- data.frame(food, group, cost, value, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>% 
  mutate(Total = 1)


# Create constraint vectors
ConVec_Cost <- df$cost
ConVec_Items <- df$Total
# Make `Group` dummy variables
  groups <- unique(df$group)
  ConVec_Groups <- data.frame(row.names = 1:nrow(df))
  for(i in 1:length(groups)){
    currGroup <- groups[i]

    vec <- df %>% 
      mutate(isGroup = (group == currGroup)*1) %>% 
      select(isGroup)
    colnames(vec) <- currGroup

    ConVec_Groups <- cbind(ConVec_Groups, vec)
  }

# New vector for atleast
ConVec_AtLeastN <- 0

ConVec_All <- cbind(ConVec_Cost, ConVec_Items, ConVec_Groups, ConVec_AtLeastN)

# Add the negative values to the matrix
ConVec_All <- rbind(ConVec_All, c(0,0,-atLeastNFrom1,0,0,0,1))
ConVec_All <- rbind(ConVec_All, c(0,0,0,-atLeastNFrom1,0,0,1))
ConVec_All <- rbind(ConVec_All, c(0,0,0,0,-atLeastNFrom1,0,1))
ConVec_All <- rbind(ConVec_All, c(0,0,0,0,0,-atLeastNFrom1,1))

# Create constraint directions
ConDir_Cost <- "<="
ConDir_Items <- "=="
ConDir_Groups <- rep(">=", ncol(ConVec_Groups))
ConDir_AtLeastN <- ">="
ConDir_All <- c(ConDir_Cost, ConDir_Items, ConDir_Groups, ConDir_AtLeastN)

# Create constraint values
ConVal_Cost <- totalCost
ConVal_Items <- totalItems
ConVal_Groups <- rep(minAllGroups, ncol(ConVec_Groups))
ConVal_AtLeastN <- 1
ConVal_All <- c(ConVal_Cost, ConVal_Items, ConVal_Groups, ConVal_AtLeastN)


# Value to be maximized
Value <- c(df$value, rep(0, nrow(ConVec_All) - length(df$value)))

# Solve
sol <- lpSolve::lp("max",
                   objective.in = Value,
                   const.mat    = t(ConVec_All),
                   const.dir    = ConDir_All,
                   const.rhs    = ConVal_All,
                   all.bin      = TRUE
)

# Solution
df[sol$solution[1:nrow(df)] == 1,]
```

Comment: I ran this example and it looks like the max price constraint is not being followed.

Comment: @AndrewTroiano Interesting mine is never above $40